# How to schedule on-chain tasks on Solana

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-lang

I have seen some task scheduling solutions:

- [Snowflake's](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solana-on-chain-cron-scheduler-is-here-7839b7d67c0) task scheduler:

  ```
  const solanaCronJob = new JobBuilder()
    .jobName("hello world")
    .jobInstructions(instructions)
    scheduleCron("0 10 1 * *")"
    .build();
  await snowflake.createJob(solanaCronJob);
  ```
- [Clockwork](https://docs.cronos.so/build/tasks/create-a-task), but currently seems to be under construction and the fees charged are not defined yet.

Is there any official/recommended and reliable way of scheduling on-chain tasks on Solana?

Answer (score 3):

Clockwork is now live on mainnet! You can use the [Clockwork SDK](https://crates.io/crates/clockwork-sdk) to create threads in your Solana programs that automatically execute instructions in the background. Threads can be triggered by a cron schedule or by listening to an account update, and they also support dynamic accounts and instruction arguments.

Regarding fees, the Clockwork base fee starts at 1000 lamports per instruction. This fee is paid the worker network to reimburse them for building, simulating, and submitting transactions to the chain on your behalf. If you have an high priority thread, you can optionally bump the fee higher so workers prioritize your threads.